# SoapFault - class not found after response

Tags: php, soap

I get this SoapFault I dont understand. Calling the function below, codewordStemExists(), should create a SoapClient which connects to a SoapServer that is up and running (no errors that I can found has been reported from the server side).

```
private static function initClient() {
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    $classmap = array(
        'CodewordStemExists' => 'CodewordStemExists',
        'CodewordStemExistsResponse' => 'CodewordStemExistsResponse',
    );
    $client = new \SoapClient("http://..../service.wsdl", array(
        "trace" => true,
        "exceptions" => true,
        "classmap" => $classmap
    ));
    return $client;
}

public static function codewordStemExists($stem) {
    $client = self::initClient();
    try {
        $req = new CodewordStemExists();
        $req->username = "....";
        $req->password = "....";
        $req->codewordStem = $stem;

        $res = $client->codewordStemExists($req);
        return (bool)$res->result;
    }
    catch (\SoapFault $e) {
        var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());

}

/** The result from var_dump: */
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://....">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:CodewordStemExistsResponse><ns1:result>false</ns1:result>
    </ns1:CodewordStemExistsResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The SoapFault:

```
Class 'CodewordStemExistsResponse' not found
```

CodewordStemExistsResponse is required at bootstrapping, it is possible to instantiate it at any time.

Anyone seen this before? Thanks.

Comment: I am usign namespaces on client side, but not server... something got messed up... works now :) Thanks @hakre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this needs proper namespacing, e.g. `\vendor\CodewordStemExistsResponse`.